# error cast connection on postgres

Tags: java, casting, connection, zk

Good night all, this is my first question.

i got some problem when running ZK application with tomcat webserver

java.lang.ClassCastException: org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection cannot be cast to controller.connection
    controller.connection.(connection.java:27)
    controller.lap_keuangan.lk_Controller.preparelistlk(lk_Controller.java:34)
    controller.lap_keuangan.lk_Controller.doAfterCompose(lk_Controller.java:30)

**this is my connection class:**

```
package controller;

//import ommited


public class connection {

  private static final String url="jdbc:postgresql://192.168.56.101:5432/adempiere";
  private static final String user = "postgres";
  private static final String pwd = "auliaardy";
  private connection conn;

  public connection()throws Exception{
      try {
          DriverManager.registerDriver(new org.postgresql.Driver());
          conn =  (connection) DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,pwd);

      } catch (SQLException e) {
          System.out.println("Driver tidak ditemukan"+e);
      }
  }

  public Connection getConnection(){
      return (Connection) conn;
  }

  public void closeConnection(){
      try {
          conn.closeConnection();
      } catch (Exception e) {
          System.out.println("gagal menutup koneksi disebabkan: "+e);
      }
  }

  }
```

**and this is my controller class**

```
//import ommited here

public class lk_Controller extends GenericForwardComposer {

    private Listbox listlk;

    @Override
    public void doAfterCompose(Component comp) throws Exception {
        super.doAfterCompose(comp);
        preparelistlk();
    }

    public void preparelistlk() throws Exception {
        connection c = new connection();
        try {
            l_keuangan lk = new l_keuangan(c.getConnection());
            List<tbl_lk> llk = lk.getLKeuangan();
            ListModelList lml = new ListModelList(llk, true);
            listlk.setModel(lml);
            listlk.setItemRenderer(new ListitemRenderer() {

                @Override
                public void render(Listitem lslk, Object o) throws Exception {

                    try {

                        tbl_lk tl = (tbl_lk) o;
                        new Listcell(ubahtanggal()).setParent(lslk);
                        new Listcell(Integer.toString(tl.getSum_debit())).setParent(lslk);
                        new Listcell(Integer.toString(tl.getSum_credit())).setParent(lslk);
                        new Listcell(Integer.toString(tl.getTotal())).setParent(lslk);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public  String ubahtanggal() {
        tbl_lk lk = new tbl_lk();
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY/MM/DD");
        long tanggal = lk.getTanggal().getTime();
        String tgl = df.format(tanggal);
        return tgl;




    }
}
```

**tomcat said error at line:**
DriverManager.registerDriver(new org.postgresql.Driver());
conn =  (connection) DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,pwd);

**i cant changed the cast connection to:**
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,pwd);

please somebody help, i got stuck over night T.T

Comment: in Java, Class names / constructors usually start with a capital letter, variables and methods with a lower case letter and do not usually contain underscores

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DriverManager object returns an implementation of `java.sql.Connection`. It won't return an instance of your `controller.connection` class. Your `conn` variable should be of type `java.sql.Connection`.

Note that:

- classes in Java, by convention, always start with an upper-case letter
- naming your class `connection`, and make it wrap an object of class `Connection`, is really really confusing. So confusing that you got confused by your own code.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
private connection conn;
```

to this:

```
private Connection conn;
```

and this:

```
conn =  (connection) DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,pwd);
```

to this:

```
conn =  DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,pwd);
```

JDBC's `"Connection"` class starts with an uppercase letter and resides in the `java.sql` package (the fully qualified class name is `java.sql.Connection`). You are accidentally using the lowercase letter `connection` which is the name of the class you have written into which `java.sql.Connection` cannot be cast.

Also, in Java, the convention is to use CamelCase for class names and class names should not start with lower case, so it's better to rename your class to something like `ConnectionUtil` or `ConnectionManager`:

```
//
// NOTE: must be in ConnectionManager.java
//
package controller;

// imports ommited


public class ConnectionManager {

  private static final String url="jdbc:postgresql://192.168.56.101:5432/adempiere";
  private static final String user = "postgres";
  private static final String pwd = "auliaardy";
  private Connection conn;

  public Connection() throws Exception{
      try {
          DriverManager.registerDriver(new org.postgresql.Driver());
          conn =  (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,pwd);

      } catch (SQLException e) {
          System.out.println("Driver tidak ditemukan"+e);
      }
  }

  public Connection getConnection() {
      return conn;
  }

  public void closeConnection() {
      try {
          conn.closeConnection();
      } catch (Exception e) {
          System.out.println("gagal menutup koneksi disebabkan: "+e);
      }
  }

}
```

Similarly, you should rename `lk_Controller` to something like `LKController`. Unless in ZK the conventions are somewhat different.

Comment: I guess you meant "to this : conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,pwd);"

Comment: your second change is the same on both lines. I think you mean conn =  (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,pwd);

Comment: omg, i was forgot my class name and variable
thanks sir its works :D

Comment: @aulia You're welcome! By the way, I hope that's not your generic password! :)

Comment: @Behrang Saeedzadeh honestly, thats not my password sir :D